Quartz scheduler standby mode in the whole cluster
I'm using Quartz Scheduler in a cluster mode. For the debug purposes I want to put all the server instances to the standby mode.
Say we have three server instances:

node1
node2
node3

A separate scheduler is running on each node. If I call the "scheduler.standby()", it will put only one scheduler to the standby mode. How to put all the schedulers to standby mode simultaneously? Can this be done from a single node?

Did you try pauseAll() instead of standby()?

I cannot use the pauseAll() because as stated here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51155691/3054099, it pauses "every now existing trigger groups, which means those new trigger groups added later will be fired normally." - and I want to pause all triggers, also the future ones, thus i need the  standby()
